# google apps script: file.setOwner() Not Transferring Ownership in Google Drive

Tags: email, authentication, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, file-ownership

I am trying to transfer ownership of all my .pdf files to another account with more space. I am testing the code with a single folder in my drive.

```
function transfer() {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('123folder-id456789-VxdZjULVQkPAaJ');
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getOwner() == user) file.setOwner('example@gmail.com');
  }
}
```

When I run the code, none of the files change ownership.

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

In your script, it tries to compare the objects of `Session.getActiveUser()` and `file.getOwner()`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

So how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function transfer() {
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();  // Modified
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('123folder-id456789-VxdZjULVQkPAaJ');
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getOwner().getEmail() == user) file.setOwner('example@gmail.com');  // Modified
  }
}
```

- In this modification, the emails are compared.

#### References:

- [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())
- [getOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getowner)
- [Class User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user.html)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Currently drive can't transefere the ownership of file that are not build-in, like pdf, zip, etc. So you must download them and reupload from the other account. I wrote a [colab](https://github.com/simone-viozzi/drive-transfere-ownership) to do that without consume my bandwith. It can recursively transfere an entire folder with both build-in file types and other file types.